# How to check if int flag is set

Tags: go

How to check if pointer int flag is set?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
)

var verbose *int

func main(){
    verbose = flag.Int("v", 0, "verbosity")
    
    if verbose != 0 {
        log.Print("I'm verbose")
    }
}
```

error

```
cannot convert 0 (untyped int constant) to *int
```

Comment: Dereference the pointer returned by flag.Int: `if *verbose != 0 …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a couple of things:

```
func main() {
    verbose = flag.Int("v", 0, "verbosity")

    flag.Parse() // <- this

    // and dereferencing the *int pointer
    if *verbose != 0 {
        log.Print("I'm verbose")
    }
}
```

From the [flag.Parse](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#Parse) docs:

> ... parses the command-line flags from os.Args[1:]. Must be called
> ***after*** all flags are defined and ***before*** flags are accessed by the
> program.

Output:

```
$ ./ff -v 2

2022/10/11 18:53:18 I'm verbose
```

Comment: Thanks it works.. I forgot `flag.Parse()` :) but how can the program both accept `... -v` and `... -v=1` ?

Comment: `... -v` should be `1`

Comment: If you want a boolean flag instead of int use `flag.Bool` instead of `flag.Int`.

Comment: I want both bool and int, because I want to set the verbosity level like `-v=1` and `-v=2` and also `-v`

Comment: The standard library `flag` package does not support flags that may be boolean or a "value" flag. To achieve this you'd need to look at either a third party package - or craft your own logic.